# How to forbid symbol in the begin and end of group of letters and numbers

Tags: regex

Here is my regex that tries to match a valid URL:

```
^(https?:\/\/((\b\w[^-][a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,33})\.){1,34}([[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})\/?)$
```

and I've tried to find way to make a simple solution to forbid the use of a hyphen '-' in the beginning and end of a group of letters and numbers.
I'd tried to use `\b\w[^-]`. But it hasn't helped.
For example, my regex matches this string, but it shouldn't
http://example-.com

Comment: Try `(?i)^(?!mailto:)(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?:(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))|localhost)(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself

```
^(https?:\/\/([WWW\.]|[www\.])?((([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][-][a-zA-Z0-9]){1,10})\.){1,33}([[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,6})\/?)$
```

its just a simple OR `[a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][-][a-zA-Z0-9]`

If you'll find better solution pls send it :)

Comment: FYI: `[WWW\.]` matches one uppercase `W` or one dot. I'm pretty sure that is not what you want.